# My codes don't apply until I press Ctrl+F5, and sometimes don't work eitherly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-studio-code, localhost, wordpress-theming

please help me on this, when I code (Html, Sass/css, Javascript), the changes don't apply until I press "Ctrl+F5" it happens every time I want to work again on my project, Im making WordPress costume theme And I use Xampp, VS code and Microsoft chromium based browser as my tools, I thought the problem from Xampp but when I install my theme on my online host, HALF OF CHANGES (STYLES AND JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ) APPLIED! then I pressed Ctrl + F5 the changes applied again, I don't know what to do, please help, until today my Javascript doesn't work its like I didn't write any Javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some few cases it's not enough to reset with F5 or even CTRL-F5. Here helps to really delete the cache in your browser.

If you use Chrome than you can disable in preferences the cache while using DevTools. This helps me sometimes. The little loss of perfomance doesn't bother me for testing.
For achieve this on Chrome press **F12** for opening the DevTools and than open the **settings**. There click on the **preferences** and mark **disable cache**.
[image]

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for paying attention

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a HTTP Caching problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

If you have the control over the HTTP server(nginx, apache or something like that), change the response header to include a `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

If you don't have the control over the HTTP server, you can adding a version number parameter to the URL.

For example:

Before `a.js` changed:

```
<script src="http://example.com/a.js?v=1"></script>
```

After `a.js` changed:

```
<script src="http://example.com/a.js?v=2"></script>
```